# How to get function return value from a multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two functions and I want to run them simultaneously. So, I tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func1():
    for i in range(0, 100000000):
        pass
    return 'abc'
    
def func2():
    for i in range(0, 100000000):
        pass
    return 'xyz'
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func1()).start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2()).start()
```

Now, how can I get return value of for example `func1()`?
I can use for example `print(func1())` to get returned value but it executes the function again and it takes a long time again to execute `func1()`. How do I not cause the function to run again to get the result?

Comment: The only "return value" from a `multiprocessing.Process` that exists is after it has finished executing there's an `exitcode` — which is a integer value. You can do what you want with a `multprocessing.Pool` though.

Comment: I use Queues to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use the `concurrent.futures` module

```
import concurrent.futures
_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

def func1():
    for i in range(0, 100000000):
        pass
    return 'abc'
    
def func2():
    for i in range(0, 100000000):
        pass
    return 'xyz'
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = _pool.submit(func1)
    p2 = _pool.submit(func2)

    print(p1.result(), p2.result())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it could be done using a `multiprocessing.Pool` as I suggested in a comment.

```
import multiprocessing

def func1():
    for i in range(0, 100000000):
        pass
    return 'abc'

def func2():
    for i in range(0, 100000000):
        pass
    return 'xyz'

if __name__=='__main__':

    funcs = func1, func2

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(func) for func in funcs]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    results = [result.get() for result in results]
    print(f'{results}')  # -> ['abc', 'xyz']
```